# Sum of restricted strictly convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Suppose that $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^p$. Also, assume $\Omega\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,p\}$ is a subset of the indices, and $\Omega^c$ denotes the complement of $\Omega$. The notation $\boldsymbol{x}_\Omega$ denotes the restriction of $\boldsymbol{x}$ to the index set $\Omega$, i.e., $\boldsymbol{x}_\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^{|\Omega|}$. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are both convex functions of $\boldsymbol{x}$. Furthermore, assume that $f$ is strictly convex along $\boldsymbol{x}_\Omega$, and $g$ is strictly convex along $\boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega^c}$, that is for $t\in[0,1]$:
\begin{align*}
    f\left( t\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{1\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega^c} \end{bmatrix} + (1-t) \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{2\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega^c}\end{bmatrix}\right) &< tf\left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{1\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega^c} \end{bmatrix}\right) + (1-t)f\left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{2\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega^c} \end{bmatrix} \right),\\
    %
    g\left( t\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{1\Omega^c} \end{bmatrix} + (1-t) \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{2\Omega^c}\end{bmatrix}\right) &< tg\left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{1\Omega^c} \end{bmatrix}\right) + (1-t)g\left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\Omega}\\ \boldsymbol{x}_{2\Omega^c} \end{bmatrix} \right).
\end{align*}
Is there a quick prove that $f+g$ is a strictly convex function of $\boldsymbol{x}$?

Comment: Is the mixed notation correct as stated? For example, the top has $x_{1\Omega}$ but $x_{\Omega^c}$, while the bottom has $x_{\Omega}$ but $x_{1\Omega^c}$. Should you have $x_{1\Omega}$ and $x_{1\Omega^c}$ in both cases?

Comment: Yes, it is correctly stated. What the first equation says is if the $\Omega^c$ component is fixed the function is strictly convex with respect to $x_{\Omega}$, and what you see is basically the definition of strict convexity for the $x_{\Omega}$ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct, even for one function alone. Indeed, let $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be defined via $f(x,y) = (x-y)^2$. Then, $f$ is strictly convex in $x$ and strictly convex in $y$, but not strictly convex in $(x,y)$. In order to answer the precise question you stated, we can consider $g = f$.

Comment: Nice construction of a counter example, thanks.